# What are these red-brown markings outlining the cells on the underside of this fiddle leaf fig?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, plant-care

While shopping at a large chain retail store, I found a fiddle leaf fig tree with a major price discount. I got excited. I’ve always wanted one. But I was nervous about the reddish-brown color around the cells (?) on the undersides of most of its leaves.

I decided to take a couple photos, put it back, and ask this community of experts!

Why do these leaves’ undersides have this red-orange-brown color around its cells? (Assuming I have my leaf anatomy straight.)

What is it?

Is it a problem? If so, is there a remedy?

Thanks!

[image: Underside of fiddle leaf fig tree leaf with brown marks]